# RestDocs does double documentation on request parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restdocs

Using RestDocs version 1.1.1.RELEASE and SpringBoot 1.4.0.RELEASE, parameters when using "httpRequest" is documented double.

The following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProductResource.class)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs("target/generated-snippets")
public class ProductResourceDocumentation {

private static final String PROPERTY_ID_VALUE = "d7612";
private static final String SALES_MARKET_VALUE = "999";
private static final String SEASON_VALUE = "2016";
private static final String SECTIONS_VALUE = "buildings";
private static final String SHOW_DESCRIPTIONS_VALUE = "false";
private static final String STRING = "string";
private static final Integer NUMBER = 1;
private static final String NOT_FOUND = "404 Not Found";
private static final String BAD_REQUEST = "400 Bad Request";

private RestDocumentationResultHandler documentationResultHandler;

@MockBean
private ProductHandler productHandler;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.documentationResultHandler = document("{class-name}/{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()));
}

@Test
public void listProducts() throws Exception {
    Product product = getBasicProductsRepresentation();
    when(productHandler.getProduct(PROPERTY_ID_VALUE, SALES_MARKET_VALUE, SEASON_VALUE, null, null)).thenReturn(product);

    mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/products/{propertyId}", PROPERTY_ID_VALUE)
            .param("salesMarket", SALES_MARKET_VALUE)
            .param("season", SEASON_VALUE))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.propertyID", is(PROPERTY_ID_VALUE)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.season", is(SEASON_VALUE)))
            .andDo(documentationResultHandler.document(
                    pathParameters(
                            parameterWithName("propertyId").description(PATH_PARAM__PROPERTY_ID)
                    ),
                    requestParameters(
                            parameterWithName("salesMarket").description(REQUEST_PARAM__SALES_MARKET),
                            parameterWithName("season").description(REQUEST_PARAM__SEASON)
                    ),
                    httpRequest(), httpResponse()
            ));
}
```

Produces the following documentation ("salesMarket=999&season=2016" is documented twice):

```
GET /products/d7612?    salesMarket=999&season=2016&salesMarket=999&season=2016 HTTP/1.1
```

Have anybody experienced anything similar or know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/286) that's been fixed in 1.1.2.RELEASE. Upgrading will resolve the problem. When upgrading make sure that you get 1.1.2 of both `spring-restdocs-mockmvc` and `spring-restdocs-core`. The latter module is where the fix is.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have now updated to 1.1.2.RELEASE and I can see that it has pulled in the correct version but I still have the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version of the core module? That's where the fix is.

Answer (score 0):

We get "double documentation" when we set a query param (see block below) to an empty string (""):

```
GET /Thing/OtherThing/Foo/?thinger=FOO&block=&bla=5&block= HTTP/1.1
```

We use Spring Boot 1.5.2 and Spring REST Docs 1.1.2.RELEASE.