# Spring REST Docs duplicates query parameter without value in curl and HTTP request snippets

Tags: spring-restdocs, spring-auto-restdocs

I'm using Spring REST Docs (2.0.3.RELEASE) and Spring Auto Restdocs (2.0.6) to document a REST API.

When the request contains a query parameter that **has no assigned value** (empty string) the snippets produced by `CliDocumentation.curlRequest()` and `HttpDocumentation.httpRequest()` show the parameter duplicated. For example:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:7001/my.app/books?code=&code=' -i -X
```

This happens whether I do

```java
this.mockMvc.perform(
    get("/my.app/books?code=")
    ...
```

or

```java
this.mockMvc.perform(
    get("/my.app/books").param("code", "")
    ...
```

This is similar to [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124663/restdocs-does-double-documentation-on-request-parameters) and [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537573/duplicate-request-parameters-being-recorded-in-the-snippet), however this only happens for valueless parameters and the bug mentioned there was fixed in version 1.1.2.RELEASE of Spring REST Docs.

Note: I assume the issue is not with Spring Auto Restdocs since these are standard Spring REST Docs snippets.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a bug in Spring REST Docs. Could you please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/new) so that we can fix it?

Comment: Thank you @AndyWilkinson . I have opened issue [#647](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/647).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this was a minor bug in Spring REST Docs that has been promptly fixed by [@AndyWilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) in this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/commit/97ddf3dcec524d0742f2b4a144d4da19b7816212), to be released in version 2.0.5.RELEASE. Many thanks to @AndyWilkinson!